# SliverListChild Delegate with ListView Causes Bottom Overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am trying to make a template view page for different text resources. It has a Sliverlist-SliverchildDelegate scrolling effect and inside has a ListView. I have tried wrapping the column with Expanded, Flex, Wrap and SingleScrollView but it either the overflow remains or error becomes incorrect use of parent widget. below is my code:

```html
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              expandedHeight: 60.0,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
                background: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          IconButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8.0, 25.0, 22.0),
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_back,
                              size: 35.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Text Reading Title'
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 35.0,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15.0),
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        maxHeight: double.infinity,
                      ),
                      child: Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Stack(
                              children: [
                                ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                                  ),
                                  child: AssetImage(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Positioned(
                                  left: 18,
                                  bottom: 15,
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                        0.75,
                                    child: Text(
                                      widget.text.textname,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                      maxLines: 2,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        height: 1.15,
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        shadows: [
                                          Shadow(
                                              color: Colors.black
                                                  .withOpacity(0.75),
                                              offset: Offset(0, 0),
                                              blurRadius: 5),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            ListView(
                              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              children: [
                                AuthorListTile,
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 10),
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                        0.90,
                                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                    child: widget.text.texttype ==
                                            'Journal'
                                        ? TextJournal(
                                            text: widget.text)
                                        : TextSurvey(
                                            text: widget.text),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: HomePageBottomNavigation(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried ```floatSliverHeaders: true``` inside ```CustomScrollView``` ?

Comment: hello @Arijeet, you mean I should include "floatSliverHeaders: true" under CustomeScrollView? I am not familiar with "floatSliverHeaders: true"?